# how to change border-top color using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is fixed table header code.
i want to change the color of the top border in fixed header using jquery.
thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).on("stickyTable",function(){navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)&&$(".sticky-table").on("mousewheel",function(t){console.log(t),t.preventDefault();var l=t.originalEvent.wheelDelta,s=$(this).scrollTop();$(this).scrollTop(s-l)}),$(".sticky-headers").scroll(function(){$(this).find("table tr.sticky-row th").css("top",$(this).scrollTop()),$(this).find("table tr.sticky-row td").css("top",$(this).scrollTop())}).scroll(),$(".sticky-ltr-cells").scroll(function(){$(this).find("table th.sticky-cell").css("left",$(this).scrollLeft()),$(this).find("table td.sticky-cell").css("left",$(this).scrollLeft())}).scroll(),$(".sticky-rtl-cells").scroll(function(){var t=$(this).find("table").prop("clientWidth")-$(this).prop("clientWidth");$(this).find("table th.sticky-cell").css("right",t-$(this).scrollLeft()),$(this).find("table td.sticky-cell").css("right",t-$(this).scrollLeft())}).scroll()}),$(document).ready(function(){$(document).trigger("stickyTable")});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is quite hard to read, so I'll give you a general answer:

```
$("selector").css("border-top-color", "#fff");
```

Comment: I think it has to be camel cased, no dashes: `borderTopColor`